# Building bootable iso using mksisofs

Tags: linux, powershell, iso

I'm trying to build bootable linux ISO under windows using mkisofs

this is the command I'm executing:

```
mkisofs -r -V “Modified Iso” -o D:\MOR.iso -cache-inodes -J -l -b isolinux\isolinux.bin -c isolinux\boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table D:\modified\iso
```

the output is:

**Uh oh, I cant find the boot image 'isolinux\isolinux.bin' inside the target**

tree.

the structure of the D:\modified\iso\ folder is:

```
[BOOT]\
EFI\
images\
isolinux\
Packages\
repodata\
sbin\
.discinfo
.treeinfo
comps.xml
ks.cfg
```

the content of isolinux folder

```
boot.cat
boot.msg
grub.conf
initrd.img
isolinux.bin
isolinux.cfg
memtest
splash.jpg
vesamenu.c32
vmlinuz
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have `isolinux.bin` in `isolinux/` ?

Comment: yes, please have a look at the question again. I've updated it so it shows the content of isolinux folder

Comment: maybe `mkisofs` wants UNIXy slashes, so try swapping the `\` with `/` in your `-b`

Comment: tried that, makes no difference

Comment: Actually, when I change slashes for -b and -c it gives me this
"Uh oh, I cant find the boot catalog directory 'isolinux' inside the target tree."

Comment: hmmm, then I would try make those arguments fully qualified paths or making your current directory be `D:\modified\iso`

Comment: what do you mean by this "arguments fully qualified paths" ?

Comment: for instance `-b D:\modified\iso\isolinux\isolinux.bin`

Comment: another thing to try: doubling back slashes, so replace `\` with `\\`.

Comment: fully qualified paths don't work

Comment: doubling back slashes example is not clear for me. Please explain in bit more detail

Comment: did you try making your current directory be `D:\modified\iso` ?

Comment: example of double bach slashes: `-b isolinux\\isolinux.bin`

Comment: I did try that. According to other topics I found online -b and -c path is relevant to the source do It shouldn't be the full path = D:\modified\iso\isolinux\isolinux.bin but just isolinux\isolinux.bin.

Backslashed didn't help as well :(